# Show/hide a div based on the model in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating my first production project with Blazor WebAssembly. I'm struggle to find a way to change the view alias DOM. Basically, I have a Razor component with a form. The user can add multiple time some information.

[image]

In the image "Add Publication Output" is

```
_model.PublicationOutputs = new List<Domain.PublicationOutput>();
```

and when the user clicks the button I add a new item in the list

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="button" 
@onclick="@(() => _model.PublicationOutputs.Add(new Domain.PublicationOutput()))">
Add Publication Output
</button>
```

then there is a `foreach` to display the new forms.

```
@foreach (var item in _model.PublicationOutputs)
{
    i++;

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">Stage</label>
                <p>@i</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="outputTypeSelect" 
                class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                Output type</label>
                <div class="select">
                    <select @bind="item.OutputTypeId" id="outputTypeSelect">
                        <option value="0">Select an option</option>
                        @if (_listOut != null)
                            foreach (var itm in _listOut)
                            {
                                <option value="@itm.ID">@itm.Name</option>
                            }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="itemShort" class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
                Short title</label>
                <InputText @bind-Value="item.ShortDescription" 
                           class="form-control" id="itemShortDescription" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I think you got it. The complete result is in the following image

[image]

When a user selects from the "Output Type" a specific value, I want to display a `div` with an `InputText`, so he can add more details. I tried to do that in 2 ways without achieve the result.

First way was to use `style` and `display` to show or hide the `div` with the `InputText` but it doesn't work.

```
<div class="form-group" 
     style="@(item.OutputTypeId == 2 ? "display: ;" : "display: none;")">
    <label for="itemDetails" class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
    Details</label>
    <InputText @bind-Value="item.Details" class="form-control" id="itemDetails" />
</div>
```

Then, I tried to use `if`

```
@if (item.OutputTypeId == 2) {
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="itemDetails" class="font-weight-bold text-secondary">
        Details</label>
        <InputText @bind-Value="item.Details" 
                   class="form-control" id="itemDetails" />
    </div>
}
```

but again, when the select changed, the `div` is not displaying. If I use the same `if` in a `label`, it is working. So, when the user selects a new option from the select, the `label` changes the text.

```
<label for="itemTarget" class="font-weight-bold text-secondary" id="labelTarget">
    @(item.OutputTypeId == 3 ? "Target Journal" : "Target Congress")
</label>
```

How can I show/hide some `div` or HTML in Blazor based on the model? Plus, how can I do it with multiple instances of the same HTML based on the model?

Comment: Already a lot of code, do we need the  "Add Publication Output" part?  But we don't see how/where OutputTypeId is changed.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have updated the post

Comment: Also, yes, the "Add Publication Output" is where I change the select. There is one select for each block.

Comment: You need to call `StateHasChanged()` after the select is changed so you'll need to use a bind on the `@onchange="MyChangeCallback"` event to a C# method. Using `@bind` is not correct here.

Comment: If I call `@onchange="MyChangeCallback"`, how can I save the selected value in the right item?

Answer (score 3):

For `@if (item.OutputTypeId == 2)` you have to update the the component view with `StateHasChanged` or better with:

```
await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
```

[See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/rendering?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-to-call-statehaschanged).

For div use a show/hide variable:

```
private bool ShowMyFoo { get; set; } = false;

private void ShowFoo()
{
    ShowMyFoo = !ShowMyFoo;
}   

for <div hidden="@ShowMyFoo">my code</p>
```

[See example fiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/v4y8ilfm).